# Get class from schema programmatically (Apache avro)

Tags: java, apache, serialization, avro

I am using [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/).

I defined the schema json string in my java code:

```
String schemaStr = STRING_IN_JSON_FORMAT;

//use Parser to parse above string to Schema object
Schema.Parser parser = new Schema.Parser(); 
Schema schema = parser.parse(schemaStr);
//How to programmatically get the class from the schema I got at this point?
```

How to continue my code to get the class from the schema programmatically?

Answer (score 5):

Avro does not generate the Java types at runtime. You will either have to write and populate it manually, use a generic Schema instance or compile the schema definition to a Java class using Avro Tools or the Avro Maven plugin. You probably don't want to do the first one.

**1. Use a generic Schema representation**

If you want to simply create a record that contains your schema data which enforces the schema, you can use `GenericRecord`:

```
GenericRecord datum = new GenericData.Record(schema);
datum.put("field1", fieldValue)`
```

This will throw an `AvroRuntimeException` if field1 is not defined in your schema.

**2. Generating a Java class**

If you have a schema that describes a Fish, and you would like to
have a corresponding Java com.example.Fish, you will need to compile
it from your schema. You can do this with Avro Tools or the Avro Maven plugin, see [the
documentation](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Compiling+the+schema). Note that the ["namespace" property](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Defining+a+schema) determines
the package hierarchy of the class.

Now that you have the corresponding Java class, there are a [couple of different ways](http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/gettingstartedjava.html#Creating+Users) to populate it with data.